# Asynchronous add to array in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

```
 var veh = [];
 app.get('/updateProf', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {


     for (var i = 0; i < req.user.local.vehicles.length; i++){
           Vehicles.findById(req.user.local.vehicles[i], function(err, vehicle) {
              veh.push(vehicle);
              console.log("GET Json: " + veh);

            });
     }
     console.log(veh);
     res.json(veh);
     veh.length = 0;
});
```

So I am doing a get request to obtain all my vehicles that a user owns and return its json, it works fine after a refresh, but when I go to the page it shows a empty array on the initial load, if I refresh the page, the array is populated. I think the issue is something to do with it being asynchronous but I'm having a hard time thinking this way and need some advice on how to tackle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes!!

You will have to wait for all of the callbacks to finish before returning the JSON.

A solution is to keep a count of how many callbacks have been executed and when all of them have been executed you can return the JSON.

```
 var veh = [];
 app.get('/updateProf', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
 number_processed = 0;
 total = req.user.local.vehicles.length;

 for (var i = 0; i < req.user.local.vehicles.length; i++){
       Vehicles.findById(req.user.local.vehicles[i], function(err, vehicle) {
         if(!err){
             veh.push(vehicle);
         }
         number_processed  = number_processed  + 1;
         if(number_processed === total){
             res.json(veh);
         }
         console.log("GET JSON: " + veh);
      });
 }
 veh.length = 0;
 });
```

Comment: So the only change here that is done is that we keep track with number_processed, and after the length of the array is equal to how many we've pushed then we can return the json. So the idea of programming like this is that order matters, and callbacks have to be tracked. Thank you so much I think this helps a whole bunch with what other functions I also have to write!

Comment: This is what libraries like async abstract. Its good to know how they work behind the scenes but you wouldn't want to write this sort of code every time. Thats why you should use async, also Achromes answer is very nice, he hits the database once instead of for every item in vehicles.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a more recent version of Mongoose, then you can directly use `Promises` that are returned by Mongoose for each query.

For example, your query can be simplified to

```
Vehicles.find({ _id: {'$in': req.user.local.vehicles }})
  .exec()
  .then(function(vehicleArr) {
    res.json(vehicleArr);
  });
```

Note that I use the `$in` operator to directly translate your loop into an `IN` condition, which takes an array of what you want to compare (in this case, it's an array of IDs)

The `then()` function just executes on completion of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Async is a utility library to deal with this.

```
 var async = require('async');

 app.get('/updateProf', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
   async.map(req.user.local.vehicles, function(vehicle, cb){
     Vehicles.findById(vehicle, function(err, vehicle) {
       if (err) cb(err, null);
       console.log('GET Json: ' + vehicle);
       cb(null, vehicle);
     });
   }, function (err, results) {
     console.log(results);
     res.json(results);     
   });

});
```